# Who is responsible for freeing resource moved by std::move?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

Consider simple code below which crashes:

```
#include <iostream>

struct test 
{
    int *x;
    test(){ x = new int;}
    ~test(){delete x;}
};
int main() {
    test x;
    test y = std::move(x);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is that when object’s resources are moved by `std::move`, what will happen when its destructor is called as natural course of object going out of scope? Does that mean we should not call `std::move` for object on stack?

Comment: Since you have no move constructor, you are really just copying the pointer, which will result in double free.  A move constructor would have set `x.x = nullptr` causing the destructor of `x` to be harmless.

Comment: There is already default move constructor?

Comment: Best resolution is to use `std::unique_ptr` for owning pointers, which knows how to move, move assign, and clean up.

Comment: @code707 In this case the default move ctor just copies the pointer. Read this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: The default move constructor (which is disabled anyway, see Praetorian's comment) would not help you, because it calls element-wise move or copy constructors, and pointers will be copied.

Comment: Maybe "rule of 3" and "rule of 5" is helpfull?

Comment: There is no default move constructor in your `test` class because of the user defined destructor. You have a default copy constructor which will element wise copy the members (if you did have an implicitly defined move constructor it would've done the same) and you'll have a double deletion when `main` exits.

Comment: Nothing was moved, so nobody was responsible. However `x` will be responsible of a double free later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does that mean we should not call `std::move` for object on stack?

No, that means that you should have provided a move constructor, which would have set `x` to null.

Note that there is no default move constructor in your case, because you defined your own destructor ([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)).

PS: Do not forget the [rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 6):

> Who is responsible for freeing resource moved by std::move?

The author of the object is responsible for adhering to the **[Rule of Five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_five)**.

Since `test` requires a custom deleter, custom move and copy operations are also presumed to be required.

Alternately, the `int *x;` member could be replaced with a smart pointer, removing the need for a custom destructor and adhering to the **[Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero)**.

Answer (score 3):

> Who is responsible for freeing resource moved by `std::move`?

The object that you moved the data to.  The object you moved the data from must be safe to use and destroy.